# Computer doesn't work with 3 rams

Tags: memory

I have two RAM sticks - each 2gb 1333MHz - working in dual channel, and I added there one stick 8gb 1600MHz. The computer turns on, and keeps restarting after 2 seconds without anything on the monitor. Dual channel alone, or single stick alone, do work.

What's wrong?

Comment: First, are you sure the new stick is good? If you install just that stick, does the computer work? If so, then maybe your motherboard only supports a single stick or all dual channel, so once you have a pair of sticks you need to install another pair. Regardless, the answer almost certainly depends on what type of motherboard you have, and maybe CPU, so you might edit the question to include that information.

Comment: Sure, motherboard is asrock p67 pro3 b3, and cpu is i5 2500k

Comment: Everythings works properly with just one 8gb stick

Comment: Related: [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/764550/109256) explains about using 3 RAM modules.

Comment: Have you checked your bios for memory mode options?

Comment: Your motherboard by the fact it does not POST does not support the memory configuration you are trying to use.  Check the manual for more information about what configurations are supported.

Answer (score -1):

Your motherboard doesn't support it specs are on this page [click me](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/P67%20Pro3/?cat=Specifications)

Comment: While your answer may be correct, it's hard to imply that from the citation given. Could you elaborate on why?

Comment: The OP said it didn't work, so it's obvious, what needs to be elaborated? He needs to move forwards not start wondering if he somehow put the RAM in upside down..

Comment: (I didn't downvote you). You claim his motherboard doesn't support 3 sticks of RAM. Some motherboards do. What reason do you have to claim his doesn't? To be clear, I have reason to believe you are correct, it's just that this information is not in your answer.

Comment: he plugged in three and it didn't work, yet they work singly, or the two identical... possibly he could use 3 identical sticks, but he didn't ask about that. He asked what was wrong... whats wrong is... his motherboard doesn't support it, ....proof is... it doesn't boot. Possibly I could expand the answer a bit I guess.