# Pairing one 16GB RAM stick of same brand and clock speed with two 8GB sticks

Tags: memory, performance

I have a PC with two 8GB 3200Mghz (ADATA D30) sticks plugged to a Ryzen 3600 on a Gigabyte B550 Gaming X Motherboard.

I have been facing memory bottleneck, and want to add more RAM to my current setup.

Is it appropriate to install one 16GB stick right now (same brand and clock speed as my current 2*8GB sticks) in either of the two free channels?

I want to buy one 16GB stick instead of two 8GB sticks, becuase this way I can keep one of the channels free to install another 16GB RAM (hopefully, same brand and same clock speed) in future if I need more RAM.

I use my PC to learn DS/ML (beginner level), and more RAM in future might be desirable.

Comment: it might work, but you'll lose the dual channel capability because [AMD doesn't support flex memory](https://superuser.com/a/764550/241386)

Comment: You are better off adding 2 8 GB modules or use 2 16 GB modules